# How to Make a Payment Button With No Set Price in PayPal?

Tags: angular, paypal

I am building application using angular, I setup a button at top of navbar. Now I just want user click on button without fill any amount and add amount after popup open. Below is my code. Please help to solve this little issue.

**Code**

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (document.getElementById('paypal-button')) {
      this.loadExternalScript(
        'https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js'
      ).then(() => {
        paypal.Button.render(
          {
            env: 'sandbox',
            client: {
              production: '',
              sandbox: '**********************************',
            },
            commit: true,
            style: {
              color: 'black',
              tagline: false,
            },
            payment: (data, actions) => {
              return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                  transactions: [
                    {
                      amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'USD' },
                    },
                  ],
                },
              });
            },
            onAuthorize: (data, actions) => {
              return actions.payment.execute().then((payment) => {
                console.log(payment);
              });
            },
          },
          '#paypal-button'
        );
      });
    }
  }
```

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are using the old checkout.js , best switch to JS SDK used by PayPal's current buttons and v2/checkout/orders API.  You can find demo code here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

For a button with a dynamic amount, you could create an input somewhere with an id:

```
<span>Enter an amount:</span>
<input type="text" id="myButtonAmount" value="" />
```

Then, when your code needs to get that amount:

```
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: document.getElementById('#myButtonAmount').value
                    }
                }]
```